# set tcl a variable from gui

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, tcltk

I want to get file name from gui. I wrote a code like below.

I am able to run all the scripts for once time. what i am looking for when i select the file form hwtk::openfileentry, i want to set a variable for the filename.

After i selected the file, if i run "set filename [$win.op1 get]" i am able to get the name. However i need automate this, i want to trigger the varible after selecting file from gui.

Best Regards

```
set win .window
catch {destroy $win}
toplevel $win -class TopClass
wm title $win "Tools"
wm geometry $win 420x200+100+150
wm resizable $win 1 1 
wm deiconify $win

label $win.01 -text "openmodel"
place $win.01 -x 0 -y 10 -width 130 -height 32
hwtk::openfileentry $win.op1 
place $win.op1 -x 135 -y 10 -width 250 -height 32
set filename [$win.op1 get]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://2021.help.altair.com/2021/hwdesktop/altair_help/topics/reference/hwtk/hwtk_openfileentry.htm), `hwtk::openfileentry` takes a `-command` option to specify a user callback script. I would imagine, based on normal usage for things Tk, that that might the place to trigger reading from the widget and writing to the variable:

```
proc updateTheFilename {window variable} {
    # Double quotes just because of Stack Overflow's highlighting
    upvar "#0" $variable v
    set v [$window get]
}

# Forming callbacks like this is very much a best practice; least surprising in complex scenarios
hwtk::openfileentry $win.op1 -command [list updateTheFilename $win.op1 filename]
```